# Can't take value from Ajax search

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

When I enter some value in form field I get ajax suggestions.
But when I click on some value from suggestions, 
I can't set it in form field.

```
<form name="form_search" method="GET" action="" id='form-for-search'>
<input type='hidden' name='search_type' value='simple'> 
<input type='text' name='q' size='30' class='search' id='searchid'>
                    <br /> 
                    <div id='result'></div>
                    <br>
                    <input type='submit' value='Search'> <br>
        </form>
```

This is my javascript/jquery code.
I was trying with changing ".live()" function with ".on()" but it didn't help.

In genully this part should work  $('#searchid').val($decoded);

But the $decoded var is always empty.

```
$(".search").keyup(function() { 

    var searchid = $(this).val();
    var dataString = 'search='+ searchid;

    if(searchid!=''){
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/po_search.php",
        data: {"search": searchid},
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){$("#result").html(html).show();}
        });
    }
    return false;    
});


jQuery("#result").on("click",function(e){ 
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    var $name = $clicked.find('name');

    var $decoded = $("<div/>").html($name).text();

    $('#searchid').val($decoded);





jQuery(document).live("click", function(e) { 
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    if (! $clicked.hasClass("search")){
    jQuery("#result").fadeOut(); 
    }
});

$('#searchid').click(function(){
    jQuery("#result").fadeIn();
});
```

});

Comment: And, where is your code?

Comment: Why not just use jQuery autocomplete http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/? And .live is deprecated so stop using it http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Could you show us your ajax result?

Comment: @David Soussan Thank you David for your suggestion I solved it :)

Comment: @nevermind thanks for your help i solved it with autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

jQuery:

```
 $("#searchid").autocomplete({source: "ajax/po_search.php",minLength: 1});
```

po_search.php code:

```
$q=$_GET['term'];   
$query="SELECT DISTINCT NAME FROM tblpartners partners WHERE NAME LIKE '%".$q."%'";



$result =mysqli_query($connection,$query); 
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $username=$row['NAME'];
        $arr[]=$username;
        }

    echo json_encode($arr);
```